# Sanitize slug title

Tags: functions, slug

i need to convert this strings into the post url:

(numbers with the point and € symbol) ex: 9.000€ -> 9000-euro

I found this function but is not working:

```
add_filter( 'sanitize_title', 'sanitize_title_extra' );

function sanitize_title_extra( $title ) {

    $friendlyURL = htmlentities($title, ENT_COMPAT, "UTF-8", false); 
    $friendlyURL = preg_replace('/&([a-z]{1,2})  (?:acute|lig|grave|ring|tilde|uml|cedil|caron);/i','\1',$friendlyURL);
    $friendlyURL = html_entity_decode($friendlyURL,ENT_COMPAT, "UTF-8"); 
    $friendlyURL = preg_replace('/[^a-z0-9-]+/i', '-', $friendlyURL);
    $friendlyURL = preg_replace('/-+/', '-', $friendlyURL);
    $friendlyURL = str_replace( '&#128;', 'euro', $friendlyURL );
    $friendlyURL = str_replace( '€', 'euro', $friendlyURL );
    $friendlyURL = str_replace( '&#8364;', 'euro', $friendlyURL );
    $friendlyURL = trim($friendlyURL, '-');
    $friendlyURL = strtolower($friendlyURL);
    return $friendlyURL;

}
```

Thanks! ;)

Comment: You say it doesn't work, can you elaborate on **how/why**? What does it do and how does it differ from what you expected?

Comment: this string 9.000€ return this -> 9-000e

Answer (score 3):

If you a look at the [source](http://queryposts.com/function/sanitize_title/) you'll see it's because the `sanitize_title` filter fires *after* `remove_accents()` is called by `sanitize_title()`.

It does however, pass the raw title as the second argument so you can perform any substitutions on the raw title, apply `remove_accents()` and return it:

```
function wpsesanitize_title_extra( $title, $raw_title, $context ) {

    $new_title = $raw_title;

    $new_title = str_replace( '&#128;', 'euro', $new_title );
    $new_title = str_replace( '&#8364;', 'euro', $new_title );
    $new_title = str_replace( '€', 'euro', $new_title );

    if( 'save' == $context ){
        $new_title = remove_accents( $new_title );
    }

    return $new_title;

}
add_filter( 'sanitize_title', 'wpsesanitize_title_extra', 5, 3 );
```

Comment: Sorry but it is not working:
Original title: You can win 9.000€
become: you can win 9.000E
and not: you-can-win-9000-euro
:/

Comment: Works for me...

Comment: :/ i don't know why... but it is not working for me.

Comment: Does not work for me either (running selfhosted WP 4.1)... it leaves me with blanks in the slug as well as with UPPERCASE chars (the € sign gets translated, however!).

Comment: @Sebastian - see update, I changed the priority as WP has a callback attached to remove spaces and replace them with dashes. This was probably running after that so 'loosing' those changes'. R.e. uppercase, I have no idea - `sanitize_title()` doesn't lowercase anything, so the problem probably lies elsewhere.

Comment: @StephenHarris thank you for the quick response - however, now I get an error: "Missing argument 2 for wpsesanitize_title_extra() in line 1" line one is "function wpsesanitize_title_extra( $title, $raw_title, $context ) {"

Comment: and this is just caused by changing from "3" to "1" I guess...

Comment: Oops, changed the wrong number. Priority is the first number (was 10, now 5) in the `add_filter` call. Lower the number the earlier it is called.

Comment: @StephenHarris NICE - now it works as expected ;-) Thanks again!